# Bash script sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to use `sed` in bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    j=$(($i-1))
    OLD="-option_something something/string1_${j}.txt"
    NEW="-option_somehting something/string1_${i}.txt"
    sed -e "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" file_to_edit.txt
    # sed -e "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" file_to_edit.txt > file_to_edit.txt.tmp && mv file_to_edit.txt.tmp file_to_edit.txt 
done
```

But I keep getting following error:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 71: unknown option to`s'`

I tried the commented line as well, but it does not work too.

It works fine on command line. I do not know what is the problem in script.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `/` in the value of `OLD` and `NEW`, which is the same character you're using as the delimiter in your `sed` expression.  So the final expression ends up looking like:

```
sed -e "s/-option_something something/string1_${j}.txt/-option_somehting something/string1_${i}.txt/g"
```

Do you see all the `/` in there?  Consider instead:

```
sed -e "s|$OLD|$NEW|g" file_to_edit.txt
```

You can use *any* character as the delimiter for sed's `s` command.

Comment: Additionally I has to use `-i` instead of `-e` as my file was not getting edited and saved but just displayed in console and original file intact.